# Is there a way to specify an image for Bing to use in search snippets

Tags: images, rich-snippets, bing

Bing will sometimes display an image from a webpage as part of the snippet when listing that page in search results, but oftentimes it seems to be grabbing an image from the page with "logo" in the file name, then scaling the image to 72 pixels high and cropping to 128 pixels wide, which often generates an ugly looking image.

I have a meta tag for `itemprop="image"` that Google+ uses, and a meta tag for `property="og:image"` that Facebook uses, but Bing ignores both of those links and goes for an image from the page. I've also seen Bing display a grayed out camera icon image as if to say it couldn't find an image.

Is there a way to specify what image Bing should use?

Comment: When you start changing things for search engines, search engines will get mad and will degrade you in search results. Don't attempt to do this. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can but it is only for certain items and categories. All the markup codes are found here on [Bing's website](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/marking-up-your-site-with-structured-data-3a93e731).

It will be done using itemscope, itemprop and itemtype, similar to the following:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
  <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
  <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
  Based on 25 user ratings
</div>
```

More can be learned at [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)

**Update:** Recipe rich snippets with photos are widely used in both Google and Bing. If you sell food products and offer unique recipes on your site, including rich snippets in your recipe pages can greatly expand visibility as shown below.
[image]

Comment: – Thanks for the link to Bing’s page on structured data. It appears images are not one of the “certain items and categories”.

Bing’s structured data page does not list anything about images (just things like events, recipes, and reviews), so it appears that Bing does not take structured data into account when selecting an image to display with the search snippet. To make sure there wasn’t a problem with my setup, I ran some of my pages through Bing’s validation tool and the structured data (Schema and Open Graph) was valid.

Comment: If you go to the recipes page. You will see image is allowed and the markup for it. https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/markup-recipes-da2b3faa

Comment: See update in answer..

Comment: I don't believe there is anything Bing specific in your answer. This would apply to Google just as much.

Comment: "This would apply to Google just as much."That is correct because the markup is based on Schema.org and therefor to answer one is to answer both.